# Alerta al iniciar sesión

Tags: php, html, login, alert

tengo un formulario de inicio de sesión, quiero que cuando me lougee, me aparezca una alerta, que me de la bienvenida.

```
<?php
    include 'conexion.php';
        $tipoDocumento=$_POST['doc'];
        $numeroDocumento=$_POST['num_doc'];
        $contrasena=md5($_POST['clave']);
        // Valida los datos ingresados, para redirigirlo a la interfaz adecuada a los datos ingresados
        $validar1=$bd->query("select*from aprendiz where tipo_doc='$tipoDocumento' and num_doc='$numeroDocumento' and contrasena='$contrasena'");
        if ($buscar=mysqli_fetch_array($validar1)) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['num_doc']=$numeroDocumento;
            $_SESSION['clave']=$buscar['contrasena'];
            header("location:aprendiz/apre.php");
        }
        else{
            echo"<script>alert('Documento o Clave Incorrecto.');window.location='index.php';</script>";
        }
?>
```

Comment: Puedes hacer que en apre.php si tiene los datos de sesión te muestre el alert con la bienvenida que necesitas.

Comment: O... podrías hacer lo mismo que en el `else` y redireccionar a `aprendiz/apre.php`.

Comment: Es mejor lo que dice @Marcos

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo apre.php:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['num_doc'])){
  echo"<script>alert('MENSAJE DE BIENVENIDA');</script>";
}else{
  echo "Aqui deberias enviarlo a iniciar sesion";
}
```

Tengo mucho sin usar PHP, no lo he probado. Espero te ayude.

NOTA: Si una sesión se ha creado y destruido en la misma ejecución, `isset ($ _ SESSION)` devolverá verdadero . Y esta situación puede ocurrir sin que usted lo sepa cuando se usa un código de terceros. Sin embargo, devuelve correctamente una cadena vacía, y lo puedes llamar antes de .session_destroy()session_id()session_start(). Si no, tendras problemas.

ESTE ARGUMENTO VIENE DE [AQUI](https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/3528085#22432014)